# Finding Standard Deviation and mean of time grouped by day of week in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics

Is this the most preferred method to obtain standard deviation and mean of times based on the day of the week?

How do I group the mean time, standard deviations first by TargetName, and second by day_of_week?

Also, how would I go about converting the series of standard deviations and means to proper time format? I have tried to loop through the series' and do datetime.timedelta(seconds=item) with success but would prefer the more pandas way to conduct operations. Thank you for your feedback.

I have a data set that has date time stamps in it as below:

```
Date        Time       TargetUser
10/10/2012  20:20:01   joe
10/11/2012  02:20:01   bob
10/13/2012  21:20:01   smo
10/16/2012  22:20:01   joe
```

I am creating a day of week column as below:

```
df['my_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['day_of_week'] = df['my_dates'].dt.dayofweek
days = {dict of days of week ie 0:"Mon"}
df['day_of_week'] = df['day_of_week'].apply(lambda x: days[x])
```

I am creating columns to tally up a total of seconds in a day and creating a column:

```
df[['HH', 'MM','SS']] = df['Time'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df['seconds'] = (((df['HH'].astype(int) * 60) + df['MM'].astype(int)) * 60) + df['SS'].astype(int)
```

I am then identifying a mean Time and standard deviation by day of week via below:

```
meantime = df['seconds'].groupby([df['day_of_week']]).mean()
std = df['seconds'].groupby([df['day_of_week']]).std(ddof=1)
```

(Not based on above data)
Expected Output:

```
Name          Day_of_week       Mean        STD
joe           mon               15:01:01    00:08:02
              tue               10:01:01    00:01:06 
bob           mon               11:11:11    00:20:30
smo           thur              07:07:07    00:03:02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to greatly simplify your work by concatenating Date and Time and then using pandas excellent datetime accessor `dt`.

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
df['day_of_week'] = df.DateTime.dt.strftime('%a')
df['seconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.DateTime.dt.time.astype(str)).dt.seconds
```

Which gives you this

```
         Date      Time TargetUser            DateTime day_of_week  seconds
0  10/10/2012  20:20:01        joe 2012-10-10 20:20:01         Wed    73201
1  10/11/2012  02:20:01        bob 2012-10-11 02:20:01         Thu     8401
2  10/13/2012  21:20:01        smo 2012-10-13 21:20:01         Sat    76801
3  10/16/2012  22:20:01        joe 2012-10-16 22:20:01         Tue    80401
```

And then to group by user and day of week do the following which renames your columns as well.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['TargetUser', 'day_of_week'])\
  .agg({'seconds':{'mean': lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x.mean(), 's'), 
                   'std': lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(np.std(x, ddof=1))}})
```

Final output of `df1`

```
                        seconds    
                           mean std
TargetUser day_of_week             
bob        Thu         02:20:01 NaT
joe        Tue         22:20:01 NaT
           Wed         20:20:01 NaT
smo        Sat         21:20:01 NaT
```

To remove the upper column level and turn the index into columns you can then do this:

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: I am atttempting this code, and it works for the most part. I primarily have a question on the method in which your obtaining a std. The data I have is showing that the std is 0 or sometimes less than 00:00:00.00002. And its troubling as i dont see that to be the case in my datasets. Any thoughts on an alternate approach? Thanks

Comment: Basically, my data is a bunch of times, the mean looks to be populating correctly, but my Stdv has no value higher than 00:00:0.000030 which i find very strange. Would this be due to the lack of data points per TargetUser and IpAddress and day_of_week? I.e. Not enough data to give a true std?

Comment: @johnnyb I just used the same function for standard deviation that you used. Try it again by removing the `ddof=1`. Also, you can get the count of each group by adding `'count':'count'` to the dictionary in the agg method.

Comment: df1 = df.groupby((['TargetUserName'])).agg({'seconds': {'mean': lambda x: (x.mean(), 's'), 'std': lambda x: (np.std(x)), 'count': 'count'}})

Comment: It all depends on the context of the problem. If you are trying to estimate the parameters of a distribution with a sample then your standard deviation will use n-1 in the denominator to be unbiased. If you data is the entire population then the standard deviation would use n in the denominator. The mean is the same in both situations.

Comment: The intent of this it to identify outliers for people logging into computers at strange times. The dataset is from a single month so I would assume its just a sample in the case you present. I am learning about standard deviations for a project at work to id strange logon times for people by day of week. Do you think the way I am going about it an appropriate way to do it? Thanks again for all your replies and assistance.